# How to group or merge these values into single record in java?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I retrieve the records from the database and store it in Iterable. It is of 'Product' type. ie.,

```
Iterable<Product> iterable;

 Name        Price   Description    Category
 Samsung     20,000  Its tv          TV
 Sony        15,000  Smart 3d tv     TV
 Moto        19,000   Its android    Mobile
 LG          18,000   Its pc         PC
```

It contains multiple rows. I need to group these records by 'category' column. If category has same value in multiple records, then that records need to be merged. And value of 'Price' column of that rows should be added up as well as 'Description' also be concatenated. I need to do in java.How to do it java?
My desired output is ....

```
  Name            Price      Description                Category
  Samsung, Sony   35,000     Its tv, Smart 3d tv          TV
  Moto            19,000     Its android                Mobile
  LG              18,000     Its pc                       PC
```

Comment: whats the o/p that you want?

Comment: I need that the rows should be merged, for example for the first two rows, I have category value 'TV'. so, that two rows should be merged together. And 'price' values of that rows should be added up and 'name','description' should be concatenated. ie, 'Samsung, Sony - 35,000 - Its tv, Smart 3d tv - TV'

Comment: You can create another Object ProductDetail,that contains three varialbles name,description and totalPrice.Create Map<String,ProductDetail> and use category as key in map.then implement logic for appending string values and totalprice  in same object of ProductDetail.

Comment: how to do the logic to append the string values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to do something like this..

Hope your `Product` class will have **getters and setters** for the below properties..

- **name**
- **price**
- **desc**

  ```
  List<String> products = getProducts();/*your List of products*/

  HashMap<String, Product> mergedProducts = new HashMap<String, Product>();
  for(Product product : products){
      if(mergedProducts.containsKey(product.getCategory())){
          Product existingProduct = mergedProducts.get(product.getCategory());

          String newName = existingProduct.getName() + ", " + product.getName();
          int newPrice = existingProduct.getPrice() + product.getPrice();
          String newDesc = existingProduct.getDesc() + ", " + product.getDesc();

          existingProduct.setName(newName);
          existingProduct.setPrice(newPrice);
          existingProduct.setDesc(newDesc);
      } else {
          mergedProducts.put(product.getCategory(), product);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: what  values has to be added in <String, String> in hashmap?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose Your class is

```
class Product{

    private String name;
    private String decription;
    private int price;
    private String category;

 // getters and setters
}
```

Create another class ProductDetail

```
class ProductDetail{

    private String name;
    private String decription;
    private int totalPrice;
    //  getters and setters
}
```

Java Logic

```
    List<Product> productList = getProductList();
    Map<String, ProductDetail> map = new HashMap<String, ProductDetail>();

    for(Product product : productList){

        ProductDetail productDetail = map.get(product.getCategory());

        if(productDetail == null ){
            productDetail = new ProductDetail();
            productDetail.setName(product.getName());
            productDetail.setDecription(product.getDecription());
            productDetail.setTotalPrice(product.getPrice());
            map.put(product.getCategory(), productDetail);
        }else{
            String name = product.getName() + " , " + productDetail.getName();
            String description = product.getDecription() + " , " + productDetail.getDecription();
            int totalPrice = product.getPrice() + productDetail.getTotalPrice();
            productDetail.setDecription(description);
            productDetail.setName(name);
            productDetail.setTotalPrice(totalPrice);
        }
    }
```